# not generating .bbl file and bibliography while using Makefile

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, texlive

I am using Centos 7.8 and bibtex to generate bibliography.

Reference and main.bbl, main.blg not generating when I use Makefile. My Makefile is as follows:

```
all: main.tex sample.bib
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main
    bibtex main 
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main 
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main
```

If I delte all files (main.aux, main.out, main.log, main.pdf) and `make`run again, no reference is being generated. This is also the case when I use `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main && bibtex main && pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode && pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode`.

But if the enter each command seperately like

```
`: pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main
 : bibtex main
 : pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode
 : pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode`
```

Then main.bbl, main.blg get generated after `bibtex main` and also the bibliography is printed in pdf. Why it does not work with makefile or when I join the commands using `&&`.

Comment: Why even use a makefile here when you can use `latexmk -pdf` instead of `pdflatex` and it will run pdflatex and bibtex the appropriate number of times

Comment: Does `main.tex sample.bib` even belong here in  a makefile?

Comment: you haven't given many clues but remove `-interaction=nonstopmode` from your "by hand" test. I would guess that you have errors in your tex that you are ignoring with batchmode, but tex will return an error status so make (and `&&`) will stop at that point.

Comment: @daleif I tried latexmk -pdf, still it does not show references properly, not only those from .bib file, also the cite of figure is showing undefined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have tried removing -interaction=nonstopmode earlier. It keeps showing undefined reference. When I run the 4 commands separately, it does not show this undefined reference at the last `pdflatex main` and generates .bbl files successfully at `bibtex main`.

Comment: Then you provide a full but minimal example example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: are you sure that you do not have errors, I still suspect that is the case. The undefined ref warning is just a warning, but batchmode hides all messages.  In either of those cases you are saying to stop on error, batchmode does not remove the error status it just hides the terminal output. I think the most likely reason for the behaviour described is that there is an error in the file.